# Aruba not working with RSpec 3?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3, aruba

I'm trying to test a ruby command line script but am having troubles running tests with Cucumber-less Aruba in RSpec 3.

Some weird errors, some obvious ones.

e.g.  weird:

```
 1) test does something
   Failure/Error: run_simple("cli_test.rb -h", true)
     ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
 # .../.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aruba-0.6.2/lib/aruba/api.rb:632:in `assert_exit_status'
 # .../.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aruba-0.6.2/lib/aruba/api.rb:750:in `run_simple'
 # ./spec/cli_test_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Looking in the code, I can't even see what's triggering this.  Trying to use Pry or Pry-byebug to check out the erroneous 2 args isn't working on it either (a whole bunch of other errors).

Then, e.g. obvious:

```
 1) test does something
   Failure/Error: check_file_presence(["bin/cli_test.rb"], true)
     only the `receive` or `receive_messages` matchers are supported with 
     `expect(...).to`, but you have provided: 
     #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::BePredicate:0x007fb36c88d6b0>
 # ... error lines ...
```

& here, the errors are obviously correct, Aruba is using Rspec 2 syntax.

So I added

```
config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
  c.syntax = [:should, :expect]
end
```

to my rspec config, but still not working.

Any ideas?  Tips?  Examples of this working anywhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some conflicts using the examples for RSpec 2, specially if you are requiring `aruba\api` and messing up with the include/extend lines many of them have.

This is the smallest example to get Aruba working. You might want to fine tune your configuration with the PATH env and things like that

```
require 'aruba/rspec'

describe "Ruba example", :type => :aruba do 
  it 'shows root content' do
    run 'ls /'
    expect(all_stdout).to include('tmp')
    expect(all_stdout).to include('var')
    expect(all_stdout).to include('usr')   
  end 
end
```