# Why does rspec 3 fail with error: only `receive_messages` matchers are supported?

Tags: rspec, rspec2, rspec3

I am attempting to upgrade a project from RSpec 2 to RSpec 3, but it is failing with the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
   only the `receive` or `receive_messages` matchers are supported with `expect(...).to`, but you have provided: #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Equal:0x007f99a974a230>
```

Here is the line:

```
expect(last_response.ok?).to be true
```

[This post suggests](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/667) one need only

```
require 'rspec/expectations'
include RSpec::Matchers
```

However, I have done this and it still reports the error. [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298665/aruba-not-working-with-rspec-3) also seemed to encounter this issue but has not been able to elicit a solution as of 3/30/2015.

I am using rspec with [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) and do not use cucumber or spinach.

Can anyone explain how to resolve this error in RSpec 3? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the line you mentioned is actually giving the error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have corrected this issue by using `extend` instead of `include` for `RSpec::Matchers`. While debugging this and attempting to integrate [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry), I [found this post](https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/1277) which suggested the change.

Thus, my code now looks like:

```
extend RSpec::Matchers
```

And not

```
include RSpec::Matchers
```